# How to implement Text to Speech with SSML tags in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Currently I have implemented using `react-native-tts` like so:

`Tts.speak('How is your day going?')`

The configuration for voice looks like this:

```
Tts.setDefaultRate(0.5, true);
Tts.setDefaultVoice('com.apple.ttsbundle.Moira-compact');
Tts.setDefaultPitch(1.25);
```

The voice is unnatural and also does not take into account text like this:

```
    <speak>
        Here is a number <w role='amazon:VBD'>read</w> 
        as a cardinal number: 
        <say-as interpret-as='cardinal'>12345</say-as>. 
        Here is a word spelled out: 
        <say-as interpret-as='spell-out'>hello</say-as>. 
    </speak>
```

It speaks out the whole SSML with tag text.